# How to plot point and vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, point

```
A = [239920.240412166 1.31193313030682;
243577.444235102 1.38185205485119;
241899.250050298 1.51264147493485;
244659.326936560 1.50845243215867;
239862.361809342 1.50810833389632;
238395.616682194 1.37125000688350;
244558.389789124 1.27212093329482;
244290.890880318 1.35116080948488;
240303.711239396 1.36064181572699;
237464.430450140 1.48857869573721;
244415.381196104 1.51252425335623;
239855.328594799 1.29178640586301;
239304.806448742 1.31075813783171;
244827.243024016 1.32080934043223;
241465.885648910 1.53667019314427;
241139.254464482 1.40424079027764;
242300.037630214 1.27160249886092;
243330.396959248 1.61411410292679;
237530.389940994 1.21846939260826];

B = [0.6 0.18; 0.15 0.46];  % green circles

for i=1:2   
    plot(A(:,1),A(:,2),'r*');
    hold on     
    plot(B(i,1),B(i,2), '-ko',...
                    'LineWidth',1,...
                    'MarkerFaceColor',[.49 1 .63],...
                    'MarkerSize',9);    
end
```

When I ploted A and B, I got this:
[image]

B(1,1) = 0.6, but it appears in 0 (X-axis). Same with B(2,1) = 0.15

How to correct this?

Comment: you cropeed your axis. that is not between 0 and 2.5, its 0 and 25000. In that scale, 0 and 0.6 are very very very close, so close that you dont see the difference,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A logarithmic scale on the xaxis will help with the view

```
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
```

However, it will lead to the fact, that now the values of `A` appear to populate one vertical line.

If you cannot live with this, you may want to try a broken x-axis. MATLAB doesn't support this with build-in functions, but there is a solution in the MATLAB file exchange

https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3683-breakxaxis

Btw: There is no need for the loop in your code. In fact you plot `A` twice on top of each other. Just

```
% Plot A and B without loop
plot(A(:,1), A(:,2),'r*')
hold on
plot(B(:,1), B(:,2), '-ko', 'LineWidth', 1, ...
    'MarkerFaceColor', [.49 1 .63], 'MarkerSize',9)

% Set x axis to logarithmic scale
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log')
```

is sufficient to display your plot

Answer (score 0):

Your x-axis goes from 0 to 250000. On that range, 0.6 and 0.15 are practically 0.
If you want you can use logarithmic scale in x-axis using `semilogx`